# How to make a plotly dash pivot table

Tags: html, plotly-dash, dashboard

Keep getting errors when running my code for a plotly dash pviot table. Getting a "Type Error" to be exact.Trying to make a simple pivot table with a global emissions csv found on Kaggle. Looked at examples online but couldn't find any solutions.

```
# Standard Imports
import numpy as np, pandas as pd, random, json, time, os

# Plotly Imports
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

# Dash Imports
import dash
from dash import dcc
from dash import html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
from dash import dash_table

df = pd.read_csv('emissions.csv')

# Create the app
app = dash.Dash(__name__)

# Define the app layout
app.layout = html.Div([
    dash_table.DataTable(
        id='pivot-table',
        columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
        data=df.to_dict('records'),
        pivot=True,
        editable=True
    )
])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

Comment: As far as I know `pivot` is not valid option of `DataTable`. There is a library dash-pivottable you could try (https://github.com/plotly/dash-pivottable). Last version release was in 2020 though so it's not very active, but you might not mind.